# Are arguments for regularization/penalties applied by default to the coxph() function in the 'survival' package in R?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I'm reading through the documentation for the 'survival' package in R, pdf link, and as I understand it, there are three methods for applying penalty to the basic Cox regression function: ridge, p-splines, and frailty.

What I am having difficulty understanding is whether these penalizing methods (with whatever base parameters they might have) are being applied to my analysis or not (by default). I am not calling those functions explicitly, only coxph().

Is it accurate to say that by default coxph() is unregularized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default coxph() is unregularized. The penalisation is only applied if you include a penalised term in the model formula.  When penalisation has been applied you can tell because the fitted model is of class `coxph.penal`